# C++: Trivia from external file

Tags: c++

I have this code, which works fine. I need to include the questions and answers separated by '?' in one external text file, which I need some help with.

Right now I have the questions and answers as follows:

```
trivia.setQuestion("Who is the patron saint of Ireland?");
        trivia.setAnswer("St. Patrick");
        trivia.setAmount(2);
        triviaList.push_back(trivia);

        trivia.setQuestion("Name Batman’s crime fighting partner?");
        trivia.setAnswer("Robin");
        trivia.setAmount(10);
        triviaList.push_back(trivia);

        trivia.setQuestion("What is the name of Peppa Pig’s brother?");
        trivia.setAnswer("George");
        trivia.setAmount(5);
        triviaList.push_back(trivia);
```

**Edit: I would like to pass the question to setQuestion(), and the answer to setAnswer()**

```
trivia.text
Who is the patron saint of Ireland? St. Patrick
Name Batman’s crime fighting partner? Robin
What is the name of Peppa Pig’s brother? George
```

I understand that I need to implement this:

```
string line;
cout << "Enter input: ";
getline(cin, line, "?");
```

And of course opening and closing the trivia.text, but how do I go about bringing the questions and answers just as if they were local?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class TriviaGame {

public:
    TriviaGame();
    TriviaGame(string question, string answer, int amount);
    ~TriviaGame() {};
    string getQuestion();
    void setQuestion(string newQuestion);
    string getAnswer();
    void setAnswer(string newAnswer);
    int getAmount();
    void setAmount(int newAmount);

private:
    string question;
    string answer;
    int amount;
};

TriviaGame::TriviaGame() {
    question = "";
    answer = "";
    amount = 0;
}

TriviaGame::TriviaGame(string question, string answer, int amount) {
    this->question = question;
    this->answer = answer;
    this->amount = amount;
}

string TriviaGame::getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

void TriviaGame::setQuestion(string newQuestion) {
    question = newQuestion;
}

string TriviaGame::getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

void TriviaGame::setAnswer(string newAnswer) {
    answer = newAnswer;
}

int TriviaGame::getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

void TriviaGame::setAmount(int newAmount) {
    amount = newAmount;
}

    // main function
int main() {
    vector<TriviaGame> triviaList;
    TriviaGame trivia;

    // === Input Stream ===
    fstream inputStream;
    inputStream.open("trivia.txt");
    if(!inputStream.is_open()) {
        cout << "File not found!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        string line;

   // while(getline(inputStream, line, "?")){
        while(getline( inputStream, line, '?')) {

trivia.setQuestion(line);
trivia.setAnswer("St. Patrick");
trivia.setAmount(2);
triviaList.push_back(trivia);

trivia.setQuestion(line);
trivia.setAnswer("Robin");
trivia.setAmount(10);
triviaList.push_back(trivia);

trivia.setQuestion(line);
trivia.setAnswer("George");
trivia.setAmount(5);
triviaList.push_back(trivia);
    int winnings = 0;
    cout << "Trivia Game!" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < triviaList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "You have $" << winnings << endl;
        cout << triviaList[i].getQuestion() << endl;
        string answer;
        getline(cin, answer);
        if (answer == triviaList[i].getAnswer())
        {
            cout << "That's right!  You win $" <<
            triviaList[i].getAmount() << endl;
            winnings += triviaList[i].getAmount();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, the correct answer is: " <<
            triviaList[i].getAnswer() << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Game over.  Your total winnings are: $" << winnings;

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `std::map<std::string, std::string>` to associate questions and answers.

Comment: @Fureeish I updated thew question. I just need to pull the question from the text and send to to setQuestion(), and the answer to setAnswer().

Comment: "*how do I go about bringing the questions and answers just as if they were local?*" - what do you exactly mean? If you read your question to `line` string, what's wrong with doing `setQuestion(line)`?

Comment: Because the question and answer are separated by '?'. I need to send the question and answer to the functions separately. Line includes both. i.e `trivia.setQuestion(questionPart);
 trivia.setAnswer(answerPart);`

Comment: I don't see that you actually try reading from a file. Please make sure your question text fits to the title.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I was going to add that later. I just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already realised what you need to do:

> `getline(cin, line, "?");`

You just need to look at [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) details and discover that it should take `char`, not `const char*` (neither `std::string`) as delimiter. Simply replace `"?"` with `'?'`.

I prepared a short example how could you use it:

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream input{"The question? The answer.\n"
                             "Another question? Another answer.\n"
                             "What is 2+2? Definitely 4.\n"};

    std::string question{};
    std::string answer{};

    while(std::getline(input, question, '?') &&
          std::getline(input, answer)) {
        std::cout << "Q: " << question << " A: " << answer << '\n';
    }
}
```

In the above example, you have two `std::string`s - one holds *the question*, the other holds *the answer*.

Don't forget to `#include <sstream>` for `std::istringstream`. If you don't know what [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) is, you can either click the link above or simply assume that for now, it's just a '*hard coded `std::cin`*'. It behaves like an *input stream* (just like `std::cin`), but can be initialised with `const char*` or `std::string`.

To make your code work with standard input instead, simply delete the `std::istringstream` part and replace `input` with `std::cin`.

To make your code work with text files, read about [`std::ifstream1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). It behvaes very much like `std::cin` (since both of them are input streams). Create `std::ifstream` object, name it `input` (or however you like) and treat it just like you would treat `std::cin`.

Comment: I was going to do the file reading, I was just focusing on the `getline` part. Thank you for the reply by the way. One last question. In the original code, once question is answered, it moves on to the next one, it's not the case in the my code.I did setQuestion and setAnswer for each of the 3 questions inside the while loop and right after `while(getline(inputStream, question, '?') && getline(inputStream, answer)) {` where do I need to look to fix this?

Comment: I just demonstrated the example of how could you extract every question and answer from an input stream (such as a file opened by `std::ifstream`). If you want to work with a specific pair of question-answer before reading the next one, you can apply the desired logic inside the `while` loop. I suspect that you want to append your `triviaList` **once** inside the `while` loop so once the loop exists `triviaList` will hold all question-answer pairs

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!!